# 500 (Internal Server Error) min.js error

Tags: contact-form

I am trying to use a contact form on my website but there is an error and I have no idea what can I do to fix it.

The problem is when I press the send button, it change to sending and it sticks to this point and no email can be send.

My form is on http://tax.indrit.xyz/test_form or [here](http://tax.indrit.xyz/test_form)

Any idea would be very helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Comment: I get the entire form from this url
https://github.com/jonmbake/bootstrap3-contact-form
Thanks for your time